# How to change the background color of terminal

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using ZSH and in the Intellj the terminal looks as follows:
[image]

As you can see, the text is not readable. 
I want to change the color schema like my terminal:

[image]

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File | Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | Console Colors, Background:

[image: Background]

See also ANSI Colors settings, they may affect the output.

Comment: I changed the background color to another color but color of ` Present Working Directory` remains the same.

Comment: It's controlled by the ANSI colors.

Comment: How can I change it? I would like to pick one from http://mayccoll.github.io/Gogh/#0.

Comment: Same dialog allows to override the default ANSI colors, see the top choice. Or you can change it in your shell.

Comment: My shell looks like the image, that I show it above. It does not apply to intellj terminal.

Comment: ANSI Colors on my screenshot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204308/discussion-between-zero-coding-and-crazycoder).